# How to pad a string with padding lengths inside an array?

Tags: java, string

Lets say I have an array of ints such as `[2,3,5,6,7]` and I have a simple string like `"name"`. How can I loop through the array and pad with every value. Supposed something like this:

Output:

```
    "  name" //2 spaces
    "   name" //3 spaces
    "     name" // 5 spaces and so on..
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
    int[] arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7];
    String s = "name";
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
     String x = Integer.toString(i);
     System.out.println(String.format("%" + x + "s", s));
    }
```

However, it gives me `java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException` at the print statement. What's the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your String.format is just a bit wrong, try below

```
int[] pads = new int[]{2,3,5,7};
String str = "name";
for (int length: pads) {
  System.out.println(String.format("%1$" + (length + str.length()) + "s", str));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an [`indent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indent(int)) method from the latest java12 release. It exactly fits your case:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
String s = "name";
for (int item : arr) {
    System.out.print(s.indent(item));
}
```

Comment: This is very new and I love it. Although I am restricted using this, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using trivial string concatenation inside of a nested for loop. The logic is as follows:

For each element of arr, print that many spaces before name.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{2,3,4,5,6,7};
String name = "name";
String pad = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    pad = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i]; j++){
        pad += " ";
    }
    System.out.println(pad + name);
}
```

This will produce output of:

```
  name
   name
    name
     name
      name
       name
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Java with version < 11:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{2,3,4,5,6,7};
String s = "name";
for (int i : arr){ 
   System.out.println(new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", " ") + s);
}
```

For Java 11+:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{2,3,4,5,6,7};
String s = "name";
for (int i : arr){ 
   System.out.println(" ".repeat(i) + s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code would work if you have put it this way:

```
int[] arr = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
String s = "name";
for (int i : arr) {
     System.out.println(String.format("%" + i + "s", s));
}
```